# Rails old validations usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-2

Could someone help me, I cannot find any information why rails core team keep old(rails2) validations in the framework?

I know, there are some advantages to use 'validates_presence_of`(for example readability), but it looks strange, because rails use both methods from different places(activerecord & activemodel) in 3rd and 4th versions without any deprecation messages.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be a good idea to tag your question with `ruby-on-rails-2`.

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues or send a pull-request deprecating the old-style methods.